# How do you use variables in a search?

Tags: search, variables

I'd like to pull out a variable something like this to save repeating the same thing

```
let s:twoLinesStartingWithWords = '^\w\+.*\n\w\+.*'
"next/previous definition
nnoremap <Leader>n /\=s:twoLinesStartingWithWords<cr>
nnoremap <Leader>N ?\=s:twoLinesStartingWithWords<cr>
```

Do I need to use the search register or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @user786441 I don't think you should have deleted your answer. It was a good description of a useful technique! It's good to have alternative solutions for future readers who may have slightly different requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include variables in mappings by building the map command as a string and executing it with the `:execute` command:

```
let s:twoLinesStartingWithWords = '^\w\+.*\n\w\+.*'

execute 'nnoremap <leader>n /' . s:twoLinesStartingWithWords . '<CR>'
execute 'nnoremap <leader>N ?' . s:twoLinesStartingWithWords . '<CR>'
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was after :)